# Prevent Buttons Inside An Updatepanel Fron Updating The Updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an updatepanel that includes a textbox, a buttun (named 'search') and a gridview.
the gridview has some bound fields (first name and last name) and 1 templated field (a button).

The user inserts a name into the textbox, click the button named 'search' and the gridview is filled with names and buttons.

That works fine and there is no full post back.

The problem is that when the user clicks the button that inside the templated field, there is a partial postback too, and I want to prevet this (The update should occur only when you hit the search button).

So how do I prevent the buttons in the templated field from updating the updatepanel?

Thank you!

Comment: Put your GridView in a separate UpdatePanel.

Comment: What are the buttons inside the gridview for?

Comment: @Jaime The buttons inside the gridview will update another updatepanel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To cause an update only when one of the buttons (ie "search") is clicked, you'll need to put the UpdateMode="Conditional" and set a "trigger" pointing to that button, something like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel Id="some" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
     ChildrenAsTriggers="False" runat="server">
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SearchButtonId" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
   <ContentTemplate>
      ....
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :)
I Did that, but the buttons inside the templated field are still causing a partial postback. Maybe I need to remove them manually from the triggers list (I don't know how to do that :S )?

Comment: Ok, I just set the Children as Triggers to false and it works fine. Thanks guys!

Comment: Now i got another problem - Iv'e added an UpdateProgress which associated with that updatePanel and that shows "loading" div. That div shows up every time I click the "search" button (as it should) and every time I click the buttons in the templated field (I don't want this to happen). What can i do?

Comment: may be add the markup as you have it in a separate question, so we can understand a bit better the problem